# Why is my Facebook page tab application is not loading?

Tags: facebook, facebook-canvas

I created a Facebook page tab application running on http://localhost:8000/. I added this application to a Facebook page which I administer.

When I try to load the app in the page tab, nothing shows up. It is completely blank. There is no iframe in the content area as there should be. No request is made to my Web server. Why is this?

How do I debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check you app settings and make sure you have the correct values there.  Also try (just for testing) to run your site on port 80 with localhost programmed into the app settings too.

Comment: The settings are correct. I cannot run my Web server on port 80 without running it as root. I'll try this later, but I don't have much hope for it since I don't see the relationship between port 80 and the app working. Is Facebook known to block non-standard ports?

Comment: I don't think facebook will allow localhost other than port 80.  I've tried a year ago and failed. It may still be this way.

Comment: It wasn't because of not running on port 80. I forgot that I set my domain to myapp.com. This is why the endpoints on localhost don't work. The error would have been easier to spot if there were validation errors.

Comment: Glad to help you find your app setting misconfiguration.  :)

Comment: @hekevintran Did you just remove that as your domain, or did you use http://localhost:8080 as your domain? I'm still having a similar problem. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I set the "App Domain" field to localhost and all my URLs start with http://localhost:8080/. The app is no longer in a page tab, but I don't think that should matter.